# max-width prevent the grid to fill all space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry for not well title, I'll try to explain better. So essentially I've two column that I've defined inside a `fluid-container` in this way:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 hideable-sidebar" id="resource_container">

            <h4>Resource</h4>

            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text"
                       placeholder="Search"
                       class="form-control" id="resource_filter" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="clear btn btn-default" type="button"
                            title="Remove">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                    </button>
                    </span>
            </div>

            <div class="results"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10" id="calendar_container">
            <div id="calendar" class="well"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

so the final result is this:

[image]

the red signs are the margin, anyway, if I set to the first div a `max-width: 250px => <div class="col-sm-2 hideable-sidebar" id="resource_container">`

I get this result:

[image]

how you can see the second column doesn't use all the space available, infact through the red signs you can see that's available other space to fill.

How can I prevent this situation in boostrap?

Comment: You are overriding the CSS in `col-sm-2` thus breaking the grid layout. What's is the reason you want to set the width to max 250 px?

Comment: @klick.klonk 'cause sm-2 is too large and sm-1 to is too small

Comment: Ok, you can either have the grid or don't, but you can't have both. Why use col-sm at all? Can't you just set custom styles?

Comment: @klick.klonk well I'm using bootstrap for get a responsive layout, why I need to avoid it in this situation?

Comment: because Bootstrap has a set width for its grid. There should be multiple ways to handle it depending on what you want to accomplish. How should the containers respond when the screen width is scaled down?

Comment: @klick.klonk well I want a max width of 250px but I don't need a static div, so for this Iìm using col-sm-2. For the moment I don't know how can solve this, hope that someone could find a nice solution

Comment: @AgainMe why not use a local version of the bootstrap css and modify it yourself to suit ur needs?

Comment: @cweitat hope in a simple way, without bootstrap core edit and so on..

Comment: You are breaking the bootstrap when you override the styles. You can add a custom class along with the bootstap.

Comment: how it should behave for `xs` viewport?

Comment: @Banzay I'm just looking for a class like sm-2 that have  a max width of 250px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A gap appears only if screen width is more than `(250/2)*12 = 1500px`. Right? Then you need to expand second column to right edge of screen. There is a solution which is **not good** by use it with bootstrap styles. You need to tune column width for media with `min-width: 1500px`:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1500px)
    div#calendar_container {
        width: calc(100vw - 250px);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but this will not fix the problem of max width